# Statistics- Set Notation

Tags: probability

Struggling with basic AS Statistical maths, Any help would be much appreciated.

The two events $A,B$ are such that $P(A)= 0.65, P(A\cup B)= 0.93$

Evaluate $P(B)$ given that $A$ and $B$ are independent. (4 Marks)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General formula: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. Now, $A$ and $B$ are independent, that means $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$. It does not mean $P(A \cap B) = 0$. Therefore
$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) (1 - P(A)),
$$
which you can solve for $P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

In general $P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

$P(AUB) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) $.